# Why do XS subs use const char *?

Tags: perl, xs

A lot of Perl XS code uses `const char *` as the return value of an XS sub but never just `char *`. For example:

```
const char *
version(...)
    CODE:
        RETVAL = chromaprint_get_version();
    OUTPUT: RETVAL
```

code from [xs-fun](https://github.com/xsawyerx/xs-fun/blob/master/chapter_03/chapter_03.pod)

Can someone explain why `const` is preferred? In my testing, the returned scalar is modifiable whether `const` is used or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's only for clarity. The `chromaprint_get_version` function returns a `const char *`, so the XSUB should be defined with a `const char *` return type as well. If you have a look at the [built-in typemap](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.24.0/lib/ExtUtils/typemap), it doesn't make a difference whether you use `const char *`, `char *`, or even `unsigned char *`. They all use the `T_PV` typemap. In all cases, the XSUB will return an SV containing a copy of the C string, which is always modifiable.